# Looking for split variant that returns string positions

Tags: javascript, string

I know that I can split a Javascript string into lines with `str.split(/[\n]+/)`.

But, I also need to know the position each line in the original string.

That is, I want

> myFunc("ABC\nDEF\n\n\nGHI")

to return

> [["ABC", 0], ["DEF", 4], ["GHI", 10]]

I'm not fussy about the exact format that is returned, and would prefer to leverage standard functions as much as possible.

So, simple answers that return

> [[0, "ABC"], [4, "DEF"], [10, "GHI"]]

or even

> [[0, 3], [4, 7], [10, 13]] ;; (start/end pairs)

or

> [[0, 3], [4, 3], [10, 3]] ;; (start/length pairs)

are all fine.

Comment: David, SO isn't a coding service. It's here to help you with _code you've written_ and with which you're having a problem. The help section has an article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm actually looking for a library service, not a coding service.  :-)

I'm hoping that someone will point me to a built-in function that does this, before I write a 10-line function to do this, that I will have to maintain forever.

Comment: Instead of `.split` you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) this function accepts a second parameter which you can use to specify from which index the search should start. Calling `.indexOf` multiple times using the second parameter will get you the required result.

Answer (score 0):

You could match non new line and get the index from matching result.

```js
var regex = /[^\n]+/gm,
    str = `ABC\nDEF\n\n\nGHI`,
    m,
    result = []

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        result.push([m.index, match]);
    });
}

console.log(result);
```